# Dart - Get pixel color of ImageElement

Tags: image, colors, dart

Is it somehow possible to use Dart to get pixel colour of the `ImageElement`? I am looking for something very similar to Canvas's context method "[getImageData](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_html/CanvasRenderingContext2D.html)", but for the `ImageElement`. I was thinking about printing the image to the canvas and then use the `getImageData` function, but this is not very nice way to do it. Thank you.

Comment: I am trying to put a svg element on a canvas myself, since I can't find any other way other than having an hidden canvas' image.

Answer (score 1):

Dart has a class
CanvasRenderingContext2D

( https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_html/CanvasRenderingContext2D.html )
with

ImageData getImageData(num sx, num sy, num sw, num sh)